# Application localization problems in english windows server 2012

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, encoding, localization, language-packs

Here's what does it look like (encoding problems):

[image: encoding problems]

- OS is Windows Server 2012, English, clean installation.
- Previously I've tested this software with same server, but with
  russian OS version, it was OK.
- I've installed russian language pack, OS language changed to russian,
  but problem remains.
- It is not in software configuration, since even installer has same
  problems, and it is very unlikely to be software problems (very
  popular and stable program)
- Software is not managed (C++), old and can use deprecated libs and
  APIs.

I'm pretty sure there's some localization libs which are included into russian OS version but not included into language packs. What are they?

May be there's a tooling which can diagnose such problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a setting for non-Unicode programs here:

[image: whathelped]

It helped.